# Reload the current page using Jquery and php after a function has been called

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to reload the current page of this php through Jquery after the user has pressed the button. The function `isset($_POST['submitGenZip'])` gets called after the button is pressed but the Jquery is not able to run its function of reloading the page. The function `isset($_POST['submitGenZip'])` is only used to download a file (that is what the php does). It does not redirect to any page.

FirstPage.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitGen']))
    {
        header('Location:Generate.php');      
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Zip Files</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
...
...
<tr>
            <form action="" method="post" role="form">
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submitGen" class="btn btn-primary" value = "GenerateZ" style="float: right;">
                </td>
            </form>
</tr>
...
...
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitGen").click(function(){
        alert("ReloadThisPage");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't make much sense. Why not just remove your jquery and set `action` in your form to `Generate.php` directly?

Comment: _"but the Jquery is not able to run its function of reloading the page"_ - There's nothing in that jQuery code that tries to reload the page?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am also trying to reload the current page (FirstPage.php). Yes because the alert message also does not get called.

Comment: If you remove your jQuery code, the page will submit to itself (reload it) and then PHP will make a redirect to Generate.php. Isn't that what you want? If not, please share some more context about what you're trying to do so the question/code makes more sense.

Comment: Thing is the Generate.php is basically for downloading a file. So once that happens, I want to reload the current page the user is on, that is FirstPage.php .

Comment: Yes but once the user is back on same page, can the page itself gets refreshed/reloaded?

Comment: I am able to download the file by clicking on the button. A new tab opens, downloads and closes itself and the user is back to the main page.

Comment: Since you don't seem to be posting any data, you might be able to remove the form and just add a link instead (you can always style it to look like a button) and do: `<a href="Generate.php" target="_blank" onclick="location.reload()">GenerateZ</a>`. (This is untested but might work). Btw, why do you need to page to reload?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the current page needs to be loaded since the file that gets downloaded should be hidden from the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your page or any other using multiple methods.

You do not have to use `PHP` to reload your current page or location. You can just do it `jQuery` OR JS instead.

**Using  location.reload()**

You can use `location.reload();` to reload your page on `click` event

Read more about `location.reload` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)

**Using  window.open()**

You can also use  `window.open('Generate.php')` this will help if you want to open the URL in the **new** window.

**Using  window.location**

You can also use  `window.location = 'Generate.php'` this will help if you want to open the URL in the **same** window.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitGen").click(function() {
    alert('Page will reload now')
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Zip Files</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> ... ... ...
  <tr>
    <form action="" method="post" role="form">
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submitGen" id="submitGen" class="btn btn-primary" value="GenerateZ" style="float: right;">
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
  ... ...
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: But this will only reload the page and does not run "Generate.php" right? The "Generate.php" is basically a php to download a file.When the user clicks on the button, a new tab opens, downloads the file and closes the tab itself and the user is back to the main page. This main page "FirstPage.php" is what I want to refresh.

Comment: @Saif use the last option in my solution if you want to go to Generate.php use window.location

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly! I have also kept a timer since sometimes the server runs late to download the file. I will post it as alternate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML onclick Event Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp)

```
<input type="submit" onclick="location.reload()" name="submitGen" class="btn btn-primary" value = "GenerateZ" style="float: right;">
```

Comment: You're missing the "after a function has been called" (eg where's OPs alert?)

Answer (score 0):

The user "AlwaysHelping" has helped me tackle the problem. However I would like to post an alternate solution. That is when the user downloads the file from the server, the request sent is sometimes slower than expected, the Jquery function runs during the same instance and the file is never downloaded. So I have kept a delay of 5 seconds in Jquery before refreshing the page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitGen").click(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "FirstPage.php";
    }, 5000);
  });
});
</script>
```